# Python 2.6 -> Python 3 (ProxyHandler)

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib2, urllib

I wrote a script that works with a proxy (py2.6x):

```
proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http' : 'http://127.0.0.1:80'})
```

But in py3.11x there is no urllib2 just a urllib... and that doesn't support the ProxyHandler

How can I use a proxy with urllib? Isn't Python 3 newer then Python 2? Why did they remove urllib2 in a newer version?

Answer (score 11):

In Python 3, `urllib2.ProxyHandler` is now [`urllib.request.ProxyHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.ProxyHandler).

```
import urllib.request
proxy_support = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({'http' : 'http://127.0.0.1:80'})
```

Many of the old `url*`libs have been merged with the`urllib` package.
[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110925021318/http://diveintopython3.org/porting-code-to-python-3-with-2to3.html#urllib) is a great explanation.

Answer (score 2):

It became [urllib.request.ProxyHandler](http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.ProxyHandler).

[2to3](http://docs.python.org/library/2to3.html) can do this for you.